# Unreal 4: Unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unresolved-external

I just created a project in Unreal 4 with C++ (Visual Studio 2019).

As soon as I build the project with only a basic movement class, Visual Studio shows these errors (see the image).

[Unresolved External Symbol error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pdID.png)

I installed Visual studio following the official guide: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/VisualStudioSetup/

This is the code in the cpp file:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "MiJugador.h"

// Sets default values
AMiJugador::AMiJugador()
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMiJugador::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    
}

// Called every frame
void AMiJugador::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AMiJugador::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);
    check(PlayerInputComponent);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("Forward", this, &AMiJugador::MoveForward);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("Right", this, &AMiJugador::MoveRight);
}

void AMiJugador::MoveForward(float amount)
{
    if (Controller && amount)
    {
        FVector fwd = GetActorForwardVector();
        AddMovementInput(fwd, amount);
    }
}

void AMiJugador::MoveRight(float amount)
{
    if (Controller && amount)
    {
        FVector right = GetActorRightVector();
        AddMovementInput(right , amount);
    }
}
```

And this is the header file:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "MiJugador.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class CPPPRACTICE_API AMiJugador : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    AMiJugador();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    // Funciones para movimiento
    void MoveForward(float amount);
    void MoveRight(float amount);
};
```

Most of the code is automatically done by Unreal. Anyone can help me get rid of these error? Thi is geting me crazy, I've tried many things as including .lib in project settings but none of those helped me...

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing (or your linker can't find) an OpenGL library.

Most likely, you are `including .lib in project settings` wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the libraries were already included and the configuration also points to the proper directories. For some reason, the project was wrong built or it was corrupted. I tried creating another project with the exact same code and it works... I think this weird things happen sometimes...